# Batch for loop in psexec command

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, psexec

I'm trying to use a batch FOR loop inside a psexec. I need to make a script that offers me the possibility to choose the subfolders (I store the items in *%list_of_items%*) in *%local_folder%* that are needed to be copied with *ncftpput* on remote server. I cannot put the entire *psexec* inside the loop because I dont want to insert every time the password.
The piece of code:

`psexec \\remote_server -u DOMAIN\user cmd /c  FOR %%i IN "%list_of_items%" DO ("ncftpput -f c:\folders\file_with_creds.cfg -R remote_folder/ %local_folder%/%%i")`

**Example**
I have:

- %local_folder%\folder111
- %local_folder%\folder222
- %local_folder%\folder333

I choose to copy the items folder111 and folder333 so I store them in %list_of_items%. For every item in the list I need to run *ncftpput* to transfer to remote server the folder but doesnt work....

The error: 
"folder111" was unexpected at this time.
cmd exited on remote_server with error code 1.
Can you help me please to find what I'm doing wrong? 
Thank you.

Comment: Start with `FOR %%i IN (%list_of_items%) DO ( ECHO ncftpput ... `. Note `(%list_of_items%)` in parentheses (no quotes) and note that operational command is merely `ECHO`ed for debugging purposes.

Comment: Thank you, I've changed the quotes with parenthesis but I get the error: _DO was unexpected at this time._